# Jupyter Ntebook. Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist:)

Tags: python, module, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

For some reason Jupyter Notebooks will not run my various projects that I was working on. Being as informed as I can, I looked at the output in anaconda prompt. I noticed my secondary python 2 environment "ipykernel_py2" was all through out the terminal's output.

I decided to check the details of my environments "Base" and "ipykernel_py2" and noticed "ipykernel_py2" didn't even have the numpy packet. Finally I decided to see if I could run/create with the python 3 kernel and it failed. I started with the anaconda installer for python 3. I had to add a python 2 kernel to run py2 code. I believe my issue is pathing. Here are screen shots and errors. I think my objective should be to ensure the correct pathing but I'm open to anything

[image]

Errors at the end of the terminal/command prompt

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>   [W 13:18:13.436 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed [W
>   13:18:13.437 NotebookApp] Kernel 92c9b5e6-e769-40c6-918d-fcf386046032
>   died, removing from map. [W 13:18:40.889 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting
>   for kernel_info reply from 92c9b5e6-e769-40c6-918d-fcf386046032 [E
>   13:18:40.893 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found
>   (Kernel does not exist: 92c9b5e6-e769-40c6-918d-fcf386046032) [I
>   13:19:40.235 NotebookApp] Saving file at /Documents/Current or
>   Active/Machine Learning/Project 1/Untitled.ipynb [I 13:46:42.246
>   NotebookApp] New terminal with automatic name: 1 [I 13:51:52.036
>   NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in /Documents/Current or
>   Active/Machine Learning/Project 1

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same error "Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel does not exist" 
After spending 2 days on this issue and searching for solution , i uninstalled antivirus from the my PC to ensure that if by any chance my antivirus is blocking my request to the kernel and the problem is resolved.

Even if we disable firewall setting from firewall ,we might know why this request is blocked ,so its better some time to uninstall the antivirus and try to execute jupyter notebook again.

Comment: Sorry bud, long gone pass this issue and I forgot how I solved it. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue. I resolved this using pip instead of pip3 for installation libraries.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).